# Does an analytic function composed with another stay analytic?

Tags: fourier-transform, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal, envelope

Assume $s(t)$ is analytic, such that it has no negative frequency components.

Will $s(f(z))$ also be analytic, assuming $2≥f'(z)≥1$?

Concretely, I work with audio  data that is mapped through a time-of-flight into space to be summed in a process called beamforming. Assuming the speed of sound is 1, the map might be something like $t = f(z) = z+\sqrt{(z+1)^2+1}+\sqrt2$, such that $2≥f'(z)≥1$ for $z\geq 0$.

Anyway, I noticed that it appears that the "analytic representation operator" seems to commute with beamforming, such that I get approximately the same result if I use analytic data to beamform an image, as when I use real data and compute analytic representation of the image s(f(z)) post-beamforming. I want to prove this holds in general as it has implications for my research.

Comment: Hi! This feels *a lot* like we're doing homework. In which context does this question arise? What have you tried to do to solve it yourself? Did the approaches discussed in Matt 's answer to your last question help, or why couldn't they?

Comment: Hi Marcus. The context is that in ultrasound beamforming an RF signal s(t) is beamformed using the time-of-flight mapping s(tof(z)), where tof(z) is something like e.g. tof(z) = sqrt(z^2+1) + sqrt(z^2+2). My previous question was an attempt to answer this question. I noticed that it appears the Hilbert transform in some sense commutes with the beamforming operation in practice, allowing me to not only sample at a lower rate using I/Q samples, but also to beamform at a lower rate.

Comment: ah now that's a field were knowledge exists, it helps if you **edit your question to include that context**! (In short, nope, when you undersample your beamforming, you get ambiguities.)

Comment: In essence, the same problem as that an array antenna system has different gain patterns for a frequency $f_0$ and its harmoninc $2f_0, 3f_0, 4f_0,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my case, it appears if I beamform with analytic data I can lower the sampling rate without introducing aliasing, as in a [digital down converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_down_converter).

Comment: well, does the analytical signal not have the original bandwidth?

Comment: The bandwidth is halved, since there are no negative frequencies for the analytic signal.

Comment: ah, but the original signal was probably real, so while you now have half the bandwidth, you need to use complex numbers to represent it – thus needing as many real numbers as before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148758/discussion-between-sebastian-praesius-and-marcus-muller).